# Getting and passing parent info to hidden form

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a WordPress plugin (called postRatings) when a user presses a nested image he adds a "like" to the page. I want to pass that info to a hidden form.

So when user clicks the `img` (that's what triggers the plugin functionality), I want to get the serial number that is in the parent `span` of that image, and pass it as a value to my hidden `form` `input`.

Thing is the serial number is displayed at the end part of the parent span id name. I wrote it in the HTML code below as “`XXXX`”.

I am trying to get that number (only) and pass it to the value of my hidden input. I started writing the JavaScript code but don't know how to continue.

**HTML:**

```
<span id="post-ratings-XXXX" class="post-ratings">
   <img class="post-ratings-image" src="1_on.gif">
</span>
<form>
<input type="hidden" id="supportedCheck"  name="supportedCheck" value="#" 
 maxlength="19"/>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.post-ratings-image').click(function(){
$('#supportedCheck').val ......?
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following

```
$('.post-ratings-image').click(function(){
    $('#supportedCheck').val($(this).parent('span')[0].id.split('-')[2]);
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9J7pX/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use following snippet:

```
$('.post-ratings-image').click(function () {
    $('#supportedCheck').val($(this).closest('span[id]')[0].id.split('-').pop());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the serial number to the id tag, consider to add it as a data tag. This is JQuery's way of working with data through HTML tags (see [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)). You can set it this way:

```
<span data-serial-number="XXXX" class="post-ratings">
```

And access it this way:

```
$('.post-ratings-image').click(function(){
    var span = $(this).parent();
    var serial = span.data('serial-number');
    span.find('input:hidden').val(serial);
});
```

Comment: the span id comes from the plugin. i might try to hack it some day but not today as im just a beginner...