# getting url and title with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get 3 pieces of info when a nested `img` is clicked (in a Wordpress plugin called "postRatings")into form inputs:

1. Serial # from the images parent `span`.
2. Full url adress of current page.
3. Title of current page.

1 is working, but numbers 2 and 3 are not... 
what is wrong with my syntax? is the method wrong?

*This is a continued question from [Getting and passing parent info to hidden form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778861/getting-and-passing-parent-info-to-hidden-form/21779548?noredirect=1#21779548), thanks to @Pranav C Balan who's answer iv'e used for the first get

HTML

```
<span id="post-ratings-XXXX" class="post-ratings"><img class="post-ratings-image"
 src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/I74mZ.png"></span>
<form>
<input  id="supportedCheck"  name="supportedCheck" value="#" 
maxlength="6"/>
<input  id="getLink"  name="getLink" value="#" 
maxlength="100"/> 
<input  id="projectName"  name="projectName" value="#" 
maxlength="60"/>     </form>
```

Javascript

```
$('.post-ratings-image').click(function(){
    $('#supportedCheck').val($(this).parent('span').attr('id').split('-')[2]);
    $('#getLink').val($('#current_url').html(url));
    $('#projectName').val($('#current_title').html(href));

});
```

Comment: what is #current_url and '#current_title html code?

Comment: You could probably just add a click to the span instead of the image so you don't have to traverse up to grab the id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `var url = window.location.href;`
and `var title = document.title;`